# What is the number of maximum comparisons intersection algorithm can perform?

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, intersection

So I have this algorithm below which finds common elements in two SORTED arrays. Given that both arrays have m and n lengths respectively, I need to find the maximum amount of comparisons this alrorithm is going to do.

```
int printIntersection(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n) 
{ 
  int i = 0, j = 0; 
  while (i < m && j < n) 
  { 
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) 
       i++; 
    else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i]) 
       j++; 
    else /* if arr1[i] == arr2[j] */
    { 
       cout << arr2[j] << " "; 
       i++; 
       j++; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I think that the complexity of this algorithm is O(m+n). Correct me if I'm wrong. So, would the maximum amount of comparisons be m+n or m*n? Or none of them?

Answer (score 2):

The worst case would be if n > m, the first (m - 1) elements are equal and the last element `arr1[m - 1]` is greater than all remaining elements of `arr2`. Then the first `if` will always fail, the code will have to pass through all elements of `arr2`, resulting in (2 * n) comparisons.

But Big O notation does not indicate an exact number of operations, but rather the [rate of its growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation/487278). In these terms this algorithm it still linear with regard to length of the whole input, and that  is written as O(n).